# Rendering the script bundle in a plain HTML page

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using HTML pages in my angularjs MVC application instead of cshtml page.
Now I am trying to bundle all the js files , I know for script rendering I can use this syntax 
    
    @System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/app/main.js")

What is the equivalent of using @script.render on a plain htm page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a normal `script` tag to load your Javascript.

`<script src="app/main.js"></script>`

Comment: Sometimes the obvious answer gets missed :) this is the result of overthinking :) thanks